# Redirecting a single url in Zend Framework based site

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm using a Zend Framework based site (version 1).

I would like to redirect users/clickers to my actual url https://www.example.com/133-8/anay-bose as they click on the example.com/anay-bose. In other words, mysite.com/anay-bose should redirect to https://www.example.com/133-8/anay-bose.

What would be the most easy and effective solution. Can I redirect via .htaccess? or Zend Redirect? Don't have much regex expertise so a hint or two might help.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with .htaccess like this:

```
RewriteRule ^133-8/anay-bose https://www.example.com/133-8/anay-bose [R=301,L]
```

Or in a controller, if you want to send the user there, do this:

```
<?php
$this->_redirect('https://www.example.com/133-8/anay-bose', ['exit'=>true]);
```